# How to create extension for UIAlertController in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to modulraise my code I am able to create extension for alertController without target

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:
            message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {_ in
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

but I am not sure how to create extension which have target and textfield(how to create and call that in viewcontroller)

my code for which i am trying to create extension

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "enter name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) {_ in

            guard let name = alertController.textFields?.first?.text else { return }

            let newTask = Task(name: name)

            self.toDoStore?.add(newTask, at: 0)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        }

        addAction.isEnabled = false

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: CANCEL_ACTION, style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "enter name.."
            textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleTextChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        }

        alertController.addAction(addAction);
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction);

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What are problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below extension that I'm using made a few changes according to your requirements.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(_ title: String?,
                   message: String?,
                   actions: [String: UIAlertAction.Style] = [:],
                   handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil,
                   textFields: [((UITextField) -> Void)] = []) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        if actions.isEmpty {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default))
        } else {
            for action in actions {
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action.key, style: action.value, handler: handler))
            }
        }
        for textField in textFields {
            alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: textField)
        }
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

A bit of advise you can always check how the parameters that you pass are accepted by the system API and customize your own function in a similar way.